# What does $$ in perl actually return?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl, learning from the beginning. I've read that `$$` returns

> The pid of the Perl process running this script.

as per below link,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm

I've the following Perl Script which is being executed on a Windows machine,

```
sub test
{
    my ($surrogate_name) = @_;
    if((defined $surrogate_name) && ($surrogate_name == 1))
    {
        print "Done!"."\n";
    }
    return $surrogate_name;
}

sub t
{
    my ($surrogate_name) = @_;
    my $record;
    my $surrogate_value;
    $record = &test($surrogate_name);
    print $record."\n";
    if ($record)
    {
        print "B"."\n";
        $surrogate_value = $$record{$surrogate_name};
    }
    print $surrogate_value."\n";
    print "A"."\n";
    return $surrogate_value;
}

&t(1);
```

In this code, I observed everything is printed except the value of `$surrogate_value`.

Please clarify me what does `$$` actually mean and why it's not returning anything in my script.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: always `use strict` and `warnings`. It looks like the `$$` here is either a typo, or a scalar dereference.

Comment: What tutorial are you reading that tells you to use an ampersand `&` to call subroutines, as in `&test($surrogate_name)`? Whatever it is, you should stop reading it as it is around twenty years out of date! Just `test($surrogate_name)` is correct.

Comment: Please don't use tutorials from http://www.tutorialspoint.com. They are terrible. Far better to look at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) and the [Perl Tutorial Hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes `$$` returns the process id of currently running script.

but in your case `$surrogate_value = $$record{$surrogate_name}` which is completely different concept that is a dereferencing.

for example $$ used along with a variable name to dereference it.

```
my $a = 10; #declaring and initializing a variable.
my $b = \$a; #taking scalar value reference
print $$b;  #now we are dereferencing it using $$ since it is scalar reference it will print 10

my %hashNew = ("1" => "USA", "2" => "INDIA"); #declaring a hash
my $ref = \%hashNew; #taking reference to hash
print $$ref{2}; #this will print INDIA we derefer to hash here
```

For more understanding read referencing and dereferencing in perl.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$$` is, as you've written, PID of current process:

```
print $$ . "\n";
```

What you've written in your script is `$$record{$surrogate_name}`, which means accessing an element of a hash and is equivalent to `$record->{$surrogate_name}`.

Other from that, `$$name` usually means dereferencing a reference to a scalar. For example, if you have:

```
my $x = 1;    # Scalar
my $y = \$x;  # Scalar, value of which is a reference to another scalar (address)
my $z = $$y;  # Dereference the reference, obtaining value of $x
```

It's equivalent to following operations on pointers in `C`:

```
int  x = 1;
int *y = &x;
int  z = *y;
```

Read more on this [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: This is incorrect. `$$record` on its own is a *“dereference of a reference to a scalar”*, sure, but in context `$$record{$surrogate_name}` is accessing a hash element through a reference to a hash, and is identical to `$record->{$surrogate_name}`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the $$ is used to print the current process ID.

```
print $$;
```

But the $ is having another work, which for dereferencing the scalar variable.
For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Input = 5;
my $Input_Refer = \$Input;
print "$Input\n";
print $$Input_Refer;
```

In the above example, we are have two scalar variable,
1. `$Input`, which contains 5 as value.
2. `$Input_Refer`, which contains the reference of an $Input variable as value.
So If we print the `$Input`, It will give the value as 5,
If we print the `$Input_Refer`, It will print the memory address of $Input.
So we have to dereference it, For that we have to use another $ like this,

```
print $$Input_Refer;
```

It will give the output as 5.