# Perl - Using strings in place of hash keys

Tags: perl, hash

in a dynamic loop i want to generate strings and then assign them as hash keys and then bind some values to each of them. what i did is (without using strict)

```
$number = 1; %clause = ();

for(condition)
  {
     if (condition)
     { 
       $name = join '', 'hash', $number; 
       $clause{$$name} =  [ @somearray ];
       $number++;
    }
 }
```

What i was expecting is to have a clause hash with keys called hash1,hash2.. etc. now it actually works, however only once, only for the last value. For example i write this code, it only outputs the very last array assigned to very last hash key. It seems $name is overwritten

```
foreach $key (keys %clause)

{ print "@{$clause{$key}}"; }
```

Can you show me how i can do this, thanks

Comment: I suspect you wanted `$name` rather than `$$name`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936160/what-does-in-perl-actually-return

Comment: Oh, and I *strongly* suggest that you always use strict.

Comment: here $name only refers to a string called hash1 forexample, so what i want is to have a key called $hash1. now i actually dont know why i wanted that, i didn't need to it seems. but still it is not the problem here - but i will try now - . And for the strict part, i cant even do it without strict : ) i will convert to strict after i find solution

Comment: @ Jim Mischel you are definitely right, that is the problem : ) thank you very much, if you write your comment as answer, i will gladly accept it. sometimes we need other eyes to see simple things, thank you

Comment: You are trying to use _symbolic references_, what is a really bad idea; a lot has been written about why and just how bad it is.  Why? In all likelihood there is absolutely no need for it. Since you don't state the purpose of this we can't suggest an alternative, but either a (normal!) hash or array, or some combination of them, should work. If straight up data structures can't capture complexity of what you want the next step is a class.   Here it seems that you simply want `$name` instead of `$$name`.

Comment: @zdim Obligatory funny, entertaining and highly enlightening [story by MJD](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), although it doesn't exactly fit here.

Comment: @stevieb Ah, yes, yes -- that one! I don't keep links around (and usually forget the title of it). It is totally "obligatory" reading :) Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you rewrite that loop slightly and build your key with string interpolation. You don't need `$name` for anything outside the loop.

```
use strict;
my $number = 1;
for my $item (@items)
{
  if ( i_care_about($item) )
  { 
   $clause{"hash$number"} =  [ @somearray ];
   $number++;
  }
}
```

Since you want a string for the key, just build a string.

Comment: Yep, I’ll clean it up.

Comment: Great. I'd still stick that `use warnings` there, on general principle

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS use `use strict;`. It would have found your problem. (`Global symbol "$hash1" requires explicit package name`)

ALWAYS use `use warnings qw( all );`. It would have found your problem. (`Use of uninitialized value in hash element`)

---

Your code uses the value of variable `$hash1` as the key. Since you never assigned anything to `$hash1`, that value is `undef`, which gets stringified to an empty string.  That means that

```
 $name = join '', 'hash', $number; 
 $number++;
 $clauses{$$name} =  [ @somearray ];
```

is equivalent to

```
 $number++;
 $clauses{""} =  [ @somearray ];
```

Simply replace `$$name` (the value of the variable named by `$name`) with `$name` (the value of `$name`).

```
 $name = join '', 'hash', $number; 
 $number++;
 $clauses{$name} =  [ @somearray ];
```

Cleaned up:

```
 my $name = 'hash' . $number++;
 $clauses{$name} =  [ @somearray ];
```

But why aren't you using an array?

```
 push @clauses, [ @somearray ];
```

Comment: sorry i just logged in saw your answer now. i actually wrote a series of codes after this question and always used strict, warnings and even diagnostics. i should thank all of you community. and about your last comment about arrays.. because i will call names and get their corresponding values. hash is perfect fit